# I can connect to my database but cannot select it at all, I need help badly

Tags: mysql, database, select

Okay so here it goes, I am going for my BA in web design, and my professor is less then helkpful in trouble shooting, and I am at the point of pulling my hair out on this. More on point I am trying to connect to a database I made, and was successful. Then I went to select the database and it tells me I am denied or as the error message states :

Access denied for user 'DataBase_user'@'192.168.1.1' to database 'DataBase_user'

and here is the code string I am using, the very same as my instructor's.

```
    <?php
$host = "DB_Host_name";
$db = "DB_User_name";
$pwd = "Password";
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $db, $pwd) or die(mysql_error());
$dbSelect = mysql_select_db($db, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
/*if ($connect == true)
{
    echo("connected <br />");   
}*/
if ($dbSelect)
{
    echo("database is selected");
}

?>
```

So any help is appreciated, its not my hosts fault, as this is the same error I have received from two different free host providers. And I have double and triple checked and my user for the database I input has every privilege he could have. any ideas?

Comment: You are currently sending "DB_User_name" as username and as database name. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable $db as both the username and password. I suggest using an array called $db which contains:
    $db["hostname"];
    $db["db"];
    $db["username"];
    $db["password"];

Make sure you set these correctly!!! Even if the database DOES have the same name as the username.

Comment: No actually, the way it's set up is, $db is the username, and $pwd is the password, sorry my not have made that clear.

Comment: Yep and I'm suggesting to use an array called $db- it will be much clearer in the long run

Comment: Do you mind giving an example, I am sorry I am still new to all this so I don't fully understand what you mean, can you give me a example using my code?